# How we can select image in Imgareaselect according pixels

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new in jQuery . I want to select image according to pixel like 145x190 , 140X180 etc .
I am able to done in ratio but not according to pixels or dimention. pls help me out . my code is:

```
function preview(img, selection) {
    var scaleX = 100 / (selection.width || 1);
    var scaleY = 100 / (selection.height || 1);

    $('#ferret + div > img').css({
        width: Math.round(scaleX * 400) + 'px',
        height: Math.round(scaleY * 300) + 'px',
        marginLeft: '-' + Math.round(scaleX * selection.x1) + 'px',
        marginTop: '-' + Math.round(scaleY * selection.y1) + 'px',

    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('<div> <img src="http://jotform.org/demo/jquery-image-area-select-plugin/images/sweet-dogs.jpg" style="position: relative;"> </div>')
        .css({
            float: 'right',
            position: 'relative',
            overflow: 'hidden',
            width: '100px',
            height: '100px'
        })
        .insertAfter($('#ferret'));

    $('#ferret').imgAreaSelect({ aspectRatio: '1:1', onSelectChange: preview ,minWidth: 100,minHeight: 100});
});
```

hope you understand my Question...

Comment: Not sure what you're after and haven't used imgAreaSelect before but if you want a fixed sized box then you can specify min and max width and height: `$('#ladybug_ant').imgAreaSelect({ maxWidth: 200, maxHeight: 150, minWidth:200, minHeight:150, handles: true });` on page http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/examples.html Then click the first ladybug image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the sloppyness, kinda tired.

If you use the code below, it does the same as my example above, except you can dynamically change the values of the [width and height through the textboxes](http://jsfiddle.net/Sj7sK/2/):

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div>
        <input id="thumbWidth" placeholder="width" value="200" />
        <input id="thumbHeight" placeholder="height" value="200" />
    </div>
    <p>
        <img id="ferret" src="http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/ferret.jpg" alt="It's coming right for us!" title="It's coming right for us!" style="float: left; margin-right: 10px;" />
    </p>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var defaultVal = 100;
var thumbWidth = $('#thumbWidth').val() | defaultVal,
    thumbHeight = $('#thumbHeight').val() | defaultVal;
$('#thumbWidth').on("change keyup", function () {
    thumbWidth = this.value | defaultVal;
    reLoad('cancel');
});
$('#thumbHeight').on("change keyup", function () {
    thumbHeight = this.value | defaultVal;
    reLoad('cancel');
});


function preview(img, selection) {
    var scaleX = thumbWidth / (selection.width || 1);
    var scaleY = thumbHeight / (selection.height || 1);

    $('#ferret + div > img').css({
        width: Math.round(scaleX * $("#ferret").width()) + 'px',
        height: Math.round(scaleY * $("#ferret").height()) + 'px',
        marginLeft: '-' + Math.round(scaleX * selection.x1) + 'px',
        marginTop: '-' + Math.round(scaleY * selection.y1) + 'px'
    });
}
var reLoad = function (cancel) {
    $('.premove').remove();
    $('<div class="premove"><img src="http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/ferret.jpg" style="position: relative;" /><div>')
        .css({
        float: 'left',
        position: 'relative',
        overflow: 'hidden',
        width: thumbWidth + 'px',
        height: thumbHeight + 'px'
    })
        .insertAfter($('#ferret'));

    var fer = $('#ferret').imgAreaSelect({
        aspectRatio: thumbWidth + ':' + thumbHeight,
        onSelectChange: preview,
        instance: true
    });
    if (cancel) fer.cancelSelection();
}
reLoad();
```

});

Comment: Note that the textbox values do not automatically select an area on the image, you have to do that manually.

I'm sure you can write a short script to automatically select an area based on the new 'ratio'

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select from the image to create a custom preview image, [try my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sj7sK/).  Just go into the javascript section and change the value of the `thumbWidth` and `thumbHeight`.  Basically it adjusts the preview image to the dimensions you are looking for and uses that ratio as the `aspectRatio`.

**JAVASCRIPT CODE**

```
var thumbWidth = 200, thumbHeight = 200;

function preview(img, selection) {
    var scaleX = thumbWidth / (selection.width || 1);
    var scaleY = thumbHeight / (selection.height || 1);

    $('#ferret + div > img').css({
        width: Math.round(scaleX * $("#ferret").width()) + 'px',
        height: Math.round(scaleY * $("#ferret").height()) + 'px',
        marginLeft: '-' + Math.round(scaleX * selection.x1) + 'px',
        marginTop: '-' + Math.round(scaleY * selection.y1) + 'px'
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {

    $('<div><img src="http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/ferret.jpg" style="position: relative;" /><div>')
        .css({
            float: 'left',
            position: 'relative',
            overflow: 'hidden',
            width: thumbWidth + 'px',
            height: thumbHeight + 'px'
        })
        .insertAfter($('#ferret'));

    $('#ferret').imgAreaSelect({aspectRatio: thumbWidth+':'+thumbHeight, onSelectChange: preview });
});
```